# Cannot assign value of type '(Array<_>).Type' to [CustomClass]

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, core-data

I'm working on a project that uses both Objective-C (older code) and Swift (newer code and any code added in future)

I've created a two new entities in CoreData model, let's call them Folder and File. Folder has a to-many relationship with File.

Here is the code for what I have mentioned thus far from auto-generated subclasses:

```
@interface Folder (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<Folder *> *)fetchRequest;
....
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<File *> *files;
....
@end

@interface File (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<File *> *)fetchRequest;
....
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) Folder *folder;
....
@end
```

I'm dealing with a Folder record in my Swift file and I am simply trying to set a property I have on another page with Folder.files relationship.

This is the property on the other (Swift) page that I am trying to set:

```
class FilesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  ...
  var filesArray: [File]? = []
...
}
```

So I'm trying to set the particular Folder record's files to that property:

```
//some other Swift file
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  ...
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FilesTableViewCellIdentifier) as! FilesTableViewCell
  let currentFolder = folderArray.last
  cell.filesArray = currentFolder?.files 
  // the line does not work I get a "Cannot assign value of type 'Set<File>?' to type '[File]?'" error
  return cell
....
```

Even when I add "(Array)" to the front of "currentFolder?.files" I still get the following error:

```
"Cannot assign value of type '(Array<_>).Type' to type '[File]?'"
```

I'm not as experienced in Swift so can anyone help me understand why this doesn't work and a potential solution? (at this point I'm going to have to just do a Core Data fetch for all that Folder's Files but I'd rather not be that inefficient if I don't have to)

Comment: Sets and arrays are different kinds of collections.  See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html.  Have you considered/tried making the `filesArray` property a `Set<File>` instead of `[File]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `files` is not an `Array` rather it is a `Set`. Set is different than array in that it is not ordered, so when you iterate through a `Set` order can (will) be different each time. `Set` however makes sure that one object can be added only once, so if you add two objects that are the same to `Set` it will contain only one object - so no duplicates.

To get an `Array` from `Set` you just do `Array(yourSet)` where if yourSet is of type `Set<File>` array will be of type `[File]`

You can just change your code to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FilesTableViewCellIdentifier) as! FilesTableViewCell

    if let currentFolder = folderArray.last, let files = currentFolder.files {
        let filesArray = Array(files)
        cell.filesArray = filesArray
    }

    return cell
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, this solution worked perfectly. Still not exactly sure why doing the if let statement first solves the issue of casting it as an array but I'll take this over the inefficient Core Data fetch I had as a temp fix

Comment: It does not cast it as array!, `let filesArray = Array(files)` this is what turns `files` that is of type `Set<File>` to Array of type `[File]`

Comment: I tend to use `if let` instead of optionals because it is easier to read and you know that you will be doing something only if some values are there and are not `nil` for optionals...

Comment: No I meant the if let is what allows me to LATER cast it as an array. Anyways thank you again for the help boss, much appreciated

Comment: Yes, either that or much more unsafe way with force unwraping doing `Array(currentFolder!.files!)`...not what you want to do